# Qt: field has incomplete type

Tags: c++, qt

Can't compile my class.
Getting error:
error: field 'filename' has incomplete type

If I change `QString filename` to `QString *filename`, error goes off.. but I need to have `QString filename`.

process.h:

```
#ifndef PROCESS_H
#define PROCESS_H

#include <QString>

class Process
{
public:
    int pid;
    QString filename;
    Process(int pid, QString filename);
};

#endif // PROCESS_H
```

process.cpp:

```
#include "process.h"

Process::Process(int pid, QString filename)
{
    this->pid = pid;
    this->filename = filename;
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: That code looks fine, I think the problem must lie somewhere else. Are you sure you can reproduce the problem with this exact code?

Comment: Is that the whole header? If not make sure you don't have a forward declaration for QString class between the QString header include and the _Process_ class declaration.

Comment: It's the whole header. If I create empy project everything works fine.

Comment: But in my project there are lots of file, that use `#include "process.h"` and `#include <QString>`.

Comment: In this case Zlatomir is right. Something forward declares your class and does so before including your header. Search your code for "class QString" and see if you can avoid this.

Comment: @Moose Oh yes you're right! There is the possibility that in a file there is `#include <Qstring>`, followed by `class QString;`, followed by `#include "process.h"`, in such case you would get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! Yes, it was because of class QString;, not in my files, but in some of QT's

Comment: And  Can you explain your solution step by step? Because if someone else wrote here that problem solved , you would have wanted know solution.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, when such weird errors like this appeared with no reason, most of the time it has been solved by changing some names, hence it was a name conflict. (but most of the time, I still didn't understand where was the conflict).

So I would desperately try to change the names of, in order:

1. the name header protection `PROCESS_H`
2. the name of the class `Process`
3. the name of the member `filename`
4. the name of the files `process.h` and `process.cpp` (if there are other folders with same file names, they will be compiled at the same place if you use qmake)
5. the name of the member `pid`, because you are really desperate at this point

Use something you are really sure it can't be already used, like `MySuperFancyProcess` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake in the header file name becouse qt alredy have "process.h". I take similar error when create file "signal.h" and clear it when rename to "signal_db.h"

Answer (score 0):

Commenting to add some clarification if anyone has this same issue. I also had a class with the name of "Process" which was the cause of this issue. I renamed the class, and the header protection to a slightly different string, in my case "AProcess"and that solved the issues.

Comment: This does not provide any contribution to the question except for repeating the other answer. You may upvote the relevant answers, once you have enough reputation. You may consider deleting this answer.