# Class definition error - Field next has incomplete type

Tags: c++

I have a very small question. Why is this code throwing the following error?

> Field next has incomplete type.

I am declaring a class, which has an attribute

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

class Node
{
public:

    int d;

    Node(int d){
        this->d = d;
    }

    Node next = 0;

};

#endif // NODE_H
```

BUT!!! If i change for a pointer works:

```
Node *next;
```

Is interesting since this is from the book cracking the coding interview.

Can someone show some light on me? (A most likely make me fell ashame :D)

Thanks in advance

I did my homework and I couldnt find the solution either [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466055/field-has-incomplete-type-error) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107410/qt-field-has-incomplete-type)

Comment: And what does this have to do with Qt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're declaring a class of type `Node` but that declaration is not complete until it reaches the closing brace and semi-colon.

```
class Foo
{
}; // Class declaration is complete now
```

However the following cannot work, see code comment.

```
class Node
{
public:

    int d;

    Node(int d){
        this->d = d;
    }

    // This is a instance of a class and as such the compiler needs to
    // know the full definition of the class. HOWEVER, this is the class
    // that's being defined (i.e., it isn't fully defined yet!)
    Node next = 0; // Assigning 0 here doesn't make any sense

};
```

> BUT!!! If i change for a pointer works

A pointer does not require a complete type (i.e., doesn't require the full definition) therefore it's fine to use while still defining the `Node` class.

Comment: I was imagining something like that. The reason for the zero is instead of having null. I want to have null because this Node class was thought to be use for a Tree, linked list, etc, ... and need  the null (or not initialized) element to understand we arrived to the end. Anyways, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @DavidSánchez Yes, zero may be used to initialize a pointer but my comment about it not making sense was when the type was `Node` (i.e., it wasn't a pointer in that case).

Answer (score 1):

That's not there error I get, that is just the intellisense error.

However, `Node` has not been fully defined yet, so the compiler doesn't know what kind of object it is, or how much memory it takes up.

Regardless, I don't think that is the problem.  Declaring a `Node` object inside  the `Node` class itself, would create a recursive dependency, and again, the compiler would not be able to resolve how much memory one `Node` would need.

Since a pointer is just a memory address and has a fixed size, the compiler is happy and it can be declared.